# How to host Openshift Free Tier on <mydomain>.com and not <path>.mydomain.com

Tags: dns, hosting, domain-name, cname

I have a Ghost Blog setup at blog-myaccount.rhcloud.com

How do I make it available at mydomain.com

CNAME cannot use mydomain.com and Redhat doesn't provide Nameservers or IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I know there should be a better solution, but if `CNAME` doesn't work, you can use an IP record instead. Having a publicly available website means there's a public IP bound to your website.

In any command prompt (any OS), run `nslookup blog-myaccount.rhcloud.com` and then add a `A` or `AAAA` record to your domain's DNS using the provided IP.

The other option would be an `NAPTR` record, such as:

`mydomain.com. IN NAPTR 100 10 "U" "http" "!^mydomain.com/?(.*)$!blog-myaccount.rhcloud.com/\1!"`

Don't use this example as-is, I'm not sure about it.

Comment: I did nslookup online , it says the name is alias of another .rhcloud.com , which itself is an Alias of Amazon aws URL and finally it has the IP.

Comment: IP is not same , it changes, they say.

Comment: Well, if `CNAME` doesn't work *and* there is no static IP, the only possibility using only DNS is this `NAPTR` record, however I am not sure how it works and documentation about it is very difficult to find. The easiest alternative would be to set up an HTTP server that would send a redirect to your blog, but you might as well host the blog on that server instead...